# Are synthesized instance variables generated as private instead of protected?

Tags: objective-c, properties, private, instance-variables

Since recent runtimes in iOS, we are able to define properties that will generate accessors for instance variables. From what I understand, it is not mandatory to declare the instance variable used since it will be automatically done for us.

For example, if I write:

```
@interface MyFirstClass
@property (readonly, nonatomic) int size; 
@end
```

and in the .m

```
@implementation MyFirstClass
@synthesize size;
@end
```

Then an instance variable named "size" will be added for me and a method called "-(int)size" will be implemented.

The problem is that when I create a second class MySecondClass which is a subclass of MyFirstClass, it seems that I can't access the instance variable size within this subclass:

```
@interface MySecondClass : MyFirstClass
@end

@implementation MySecondClass
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        size = 10;  // this yields and error
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Are the automatically created instance variables private? Is there a possibility to set them as protected so I can access them in subclasses?
I know there is the possibility to declare the instance variable myself, but I'm just wondering...

With a superclass like this it works: (Is it because it's expressly declared as protected?)

```
@interface MyFirstClass {
    int size;  // defined expressly and used as @protected
}
@property (readonly, nonatomic) int size;
@end
```

Thank you for your help!!
Nicolas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any instance variable not declared in the main interface is automatically private, and this cannot be overridden. If you try to use a scope modifier when defining instance variables in the implementation, you will get an error that the specification is inconsistent.

The reason for this is that there is usually only one class per implementation file, which means the compiler doesn't know about the instance variable when compiling other classes. If you have multiple classes in the same file, the compiler could know about it, but you still aren't allowed to override the scope. Possible reasons in this case could be for consistency, or just so the compiler doesn't have to look in so many places for instance variables.

Comment: Ok so this means that I have to declare the variable in the interface in order to be able to directly access it in subclasses, right?
Automatically created instance variables are in fact private.

Comment: Right. That is the only place the compiler will look for superclass instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
self.size = 10;
```

That will map to setSize method.

Comment: I think it won't work since I asked no setter, I'm I right? Thanks.

Comment: setter is only if you want to change the default setter to use another name or another variable name.  Try it!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I don't want any public setter here, this is supposed to be a protected variable. Can you clarify?

Comment: The problem here is not the setter, it's why can't I access the variable in subclasses just with the name (direct access).