# _underbar variable usage in subclasses with auto-synthesized properties?

Tags: objective-c

Ran into this today in Xcode 4.6 and it caught me by surprise. I am using auto-synthesized properties (but manual synthesis makes no difference).

```
@interface TestA : NSObject
@property (strong) id foo;
@end

#import "TestA.h"
@interface TestB : TestA
- (id)initWithFoo:(id)foo;
@end

@implementation TestB
- (id)initWithFoo:(id)foo
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _foo = foo; // Xcode says _foo is not defined.
        //self.foo = foo; // This does work though.
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

I can access `_foo` in `TestA`'s implementation just fine but not in `TestB`'s. I can fix this by putting `id _userInfo` as an ivar declaration in `TestA.h` but I didn't think I would have to. What is happening here?

Comment: Scope. It seems that autogenerated ivars are `@private` by default and not `@protected`.

Comment: Here is a [good explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9244885/300798) why automatically generated ivars are private.

Comment: That definitely seems like what's going on but it's still a bit surprising. I'd figure it would be @protected, especially since I'm pretty sure I've seen Apple recommend not using properties in init and release methods in WWDC talks.

Comment: Since `foo` exists on `TestA`, the typical approach to this would be to have `initWithFoo:` exist on `TestA` rather than in `TestB`. Adding it in `TestB` suggests a somewhat strange design (so not surprising that you get somewhat strange implementation).

Comment: It's sort of _more_ than `@private`: [What is the visibility of @synthesized instance variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510464/what-is-the-visibility-of-synthesized-instance-variables)

Comment: You can define `@interface TestA : NSObject { id _foo;}` then _foo is protected. Autosynthesize still works and you don't have to manually do `@synthesize id foo = _foo;`